# How to run batch file command line argument on another server?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, command-line-arguments

I have **Encrypt.bat** on **\\RDWAPPserver** which contains code to encrypt the file and upload it to FTP server by using 2 commandline parameters.

Encrypt.bat needs 2 commandline parameters exl: **\\rdwtestserver\encrypt\file1.out** and **\\rdwtest1server\encrypt.txt**

I need to run Encrypt.bat from **\\RDWQAtestserver** in such a way that Encrypt.bat will run on **\\RDWAPPserver** with commandline parameters

Comment: You need someone/something to run the script for you on that server.  You cannot do this using just ftp.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: I have all functionality in Encrypt.bat... is there any way to run this batch file with argument on RDWAPPserver from RDWQAtestserver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PsExec is probably what you're looking for.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Usage: psexec [\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]

Comment: is it possible without using psexec.exe?

Comment: Sure. The other method involves using WMIC, I.e.:

C:\> wmic /node:[targetIPaddr] /user:[admin] process call create "cmd.exe /c [command]"

Or you could call WMI functions from inside a VBScript as mentioned in https://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-run-remote-windows-commands/#method-2-use-wmi-to-run-remote-commands
The other options would be to install an external program to do this for you (OpenSSH/FreeSSHd/WinSSHd, or a commercial one like ControlUp)